# Merge Multiples Accounts by Selecting a CheckBox

Tags: apex, visualforce, merge

I have an app to show iteratively the IDs by selecting a checkBox. I need to merge the selected accounts, how can I do that?

This is the Controller:

```
public class MyAccountListCntrlr {
// PROPERTIES
public List<AccountWrapperCls> acctList {get;set;}
public Set<String> selAccountNames {get;set;}
public Boolean hasSelAcct {get;set;}
public static List<Account> accts;

//  MESSAGE
public static  Boolean showMessage {get;set;}
public static String message {get;set;}


 // CONSTRUCTOR
 public MyAccountListCntrlr(){
      acctList = new List<AccountWrapperCls>();
      selAccountNames = new Set<String>();
     showMessage = false;
      for(Account a : [SELECT AccountNumber, name, id, phone, fax, website, type, industry, description, NumberOfEmployees, BillingCity, AnnualRevenue from account
      LIMIT 10]){
           acctList.add(new AccountWrapperCls(a));
      }
 }

 // METHODS
 public void displaySelectedAccountNumbers(){
      //selAccountNames.clear();
      hasSelAcct = false;
      for(AccountWrapperCls cWrapper : acctList){
           if(cWrapper.isSelected){
                hasSelAcct = true;
                selAccountNames.add(cWrapper.cAccount.id);
                //showMessage = true;
                //message = 'The following error has ocurred: \n' + cWrapper.cAccount.id;
                //accts.add(cWrapper.cAccount);
           }
           if(selAccountNames.size() > 1)
            {
                for(Integer i = 1; i < selAccountNames.size(); i++)
                {
                    showMessage = true;
                    message = ' The selected accounts are: \n' + selAccountNames;
                } 
            }
      }
   }
```

}

I am also use a Wrapper Class such the following:

```
public class AccountWrapperCls {
 public Boolean isSelected {get;set;}
 public Account cAccount {get;set;}     

 public AccountWrapperCls(Account cAccount){
      this.cAccount = cAccount; } }//End AccountWrapperCls
```

And this is the VisualForce Page:

```
<apex:page controller="MyAccountListCntrlr" tabStyle="Account">
```

```
     <!-- ACCOUNT LIST -->
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acctList}" var="acctWrapper">
        <apex:column >
           <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!acctWrapper.isSelected}"/>
        </apex:column> 
        <apex:column value="{!acctWrapper.cAccount.AccountNumber}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!acctWrapper.cAccount.Name}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!acctWrapper.cAccount.website}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockTable>

      <!--//Message-->
         <apex:outputText rendered="{!showMessage}" id="tests">
             <script>
             alert("{!JSENCODE(message)}")
             </script>
         </apex:outputText>

     <!-- SELECTED ACCOUNT INFO -->
     <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="{!hasSelAcct}">
           <apex:outputText value="Below are the selected account:"/>
           <br/>
           <apex:outputText value="{!selAccountNames}"/>
         </apex:outputPanel>
         <apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="{!NOT(hasSelAcct)}">
            <br/>
            <apex:outputText value="No account selected."/>
         </apex:outputPanel>
     </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
```

How can I merge the selected accounts? Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean `merge the selected accounts ` ?

Comment: When you click on show selected accounts you will see the id of all accounts you have selected. Now I need to merge those same selected accounts.

Comment: Just check `cWrapper.isSelected == true`  and add into new list.

Comment: Merge method only allows to merge two records (Accounts) at once, if you notice the at clicking on show selected accounts, you will be able to watch all selected accounts. I don't know how extract those IDs from that for statement to create the merge method. Can you help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your selected accounts, you're going to need a method that takes the selected accounts and uses the `merge(masterRecord, duplicateRecords)` on them which is limited to 2 records that can be merged with the `masterRecord`. That suggests to me that you're going to need to have two selection methods here, one for the masterRecord and another for up to two secondary records.

The secondary accounts can be added to a list. I also recommend you use the `database.MergeResult` class along with allowing partial success, then reporting back the results using Apex.Page Messages.

**Edit**

I think you're going to need two sets of checkboxes, one for the primary account and the 2nd for the accounts to be merged with it. The 2nd can be a multi-select list with a limit of 2 accounts.

Presumably, you could use a `getselectedMasterAccount` apex properties or something similar to capture the master account. Create a Method if you want to, but I don't think it's necessary.

With your other checkboxes, you'll want to do a for loop on them to find out which ones have been selected and add them to a list of accounts as you do. If it's size is greater than 2, pop up a page message of some kind, if not, proceed with your DML.

I'd do that using a command button that calls the merge method. Static list methods are not the way to go. In fact, you should be able to do this using a void method unless you want to redirect to the account detail page afterward.

Comment: That's the issue I got, I don't know how to do that because the variable is temporal.

Comment: I also tried this: public static List<Account> account1 = [Select id, name, phone FROM account where id = :selAccountNames];
         public static List<Account> account2 = [Select id, name, phone FROM account where id = :selAccountNames];
                        merge account1 account2;  but it showed me this: Only top-level class variables can be declared static

Comment: The problem is (The 2nd can be a multi-select list with a limit of 2 accounts.) I need to merge all accounts at once. I can store all the merged information in description.

Comment: Look at the formula for merge. It includes `(target account, list(accts to merge)`. You need to separate the two. Unless your method is going to choose the Parent acct to merge to on it's own and not allow the user to choose that account, then won't you want to give the user a means to choose that account? You can always locate the checkboxes in two places, not side by side. E.G. put the Parent box after the account name.

Comment: I would use a single Apex property for the Parent Acct getter and a method to get the list of accounts to merge with it that puts those accounts into a list.